# Prove that for a $n\times n$ matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ ($n$ is odd), $det(A)$ is even if $a_{ii}$ is even and $a_{ij}+a_{ji}$ is even ($i\neq j$)?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a linear algebra problem regarding a sufficient condition for the determinant of an odd-order square matrix to be even. As said above, if all elements along the main diagonal are even, and the sum of any pair of symmetric elements is even, how can we prove that the determinant is even?
I've learned the methods of calculating determinants and the properties of matrices, but I struggle to prove it. I tried induction along with Laplace expansion, but it doesn't seem to help. Or regarding the definition of determinant, I thought the key point might be a product is even as long as one factor is even, but I find it challeging as the statement only provides that the sum of symmetric entries is even. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: [This post is related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2065868/81360)

Comment: TheStudent's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3667513/1508) to Magic Unicorn's question [Diagonal elements and determinant of an antisymmetric matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3667495/1508) solves your problem, if you are comfortable with finite fields. Your  matrix is antisymmetric over $GF(2)$ (the field with two elements $0$ and $1$); so  its determinant is $0$ modulo $2$, i.e. it is even.

Comment: @TonyK Antisymmetric matrices in $GF(2)$ need not have zero determinant. For example, the identity matrix is antisymmetric in $GF(2)$.

Comment: @TonyK But in GF(2), $1 = -1$

Comment: @Alex_123 How much do you know about modular arithmetic?

Comment: @BenGrossmann: Oh, you're right! The proof falls down at the stage "$\det A=\det A^T=-\det A$, therefore $\det A=0$". Of course in $GF(2)$ $x=-x$ for all $x$...

Comment: the answer I gave here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4018680/connecting-the-rank-with-the-determinant-of-a-skew-symmetric-matrix/4019432#4019432 is relevant and in line with what @TonyK said.  In characteristic 2 we just need to be careful on definitions -- define skew symmetry to refer to totally isotropic bilinear forms -- i.e. in characteristic 2 this equates to a symmetric matrix with zeros on the diagonal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\det(A)$ is a polynomial over the entries of $A$. Thus, if $A \equiv B \pmod 2$, then it follows that $\det(A) \equiv \det(B) \pmod 2$. So, let $B$ be the matrix obtained by replacing each entry $a_{i,j}$ with $0$ if $a_{i,j}$ is even, with $1$ if $a_{i,j}$ is odd and $i < j$, and with $-1$ if $a_{i,j}$ is odd and $i > j$.

Note that $B$ is an antisymmetric matrix with an odd size. It follows that $\det(B) = 0$. Thus, we have
$$
\det(A) \equiv \det(B) = 0 \pmod 2.
$$
So, $\det(A)$ is equal to $0$ modulo $2$, which is to say that $\det(A)$ is even, which is what we wanted.

Comment: Thanks for rescuing my botched attempt!

Comment: @TonyK It was the right general idea for sure

Comment: Thanks! I just worked on a problem related to anti-symmetric matrix of odd order, but didn't link them together.

Comment: @DanielV I am not merely saying that $B$ is an antisymmetric matrix modulo 2, I am saying that $B$ is an antisymmetric matrix *with integer entries* (rather than with entries in $\Bbb F_2$). Unlike $B$, $I_3$ is not an antisymmetric matrix with integer entries, though it would be antisymmetric over $\Bbb F_2$. And no, stating that antisymmetric matrices of odd sizes (with entries in a field of characteristic 0) have a 0 determinant is not "restating the question" in any reasonable sense